# PHP how to display text from input tag correctly

Tags: php, character-encoding

when i echo something from an input (form in html) to php

the input value in html was:

```
强化课程
```

the echo (php) output was:

```
å¼ºåŒ–è¯¾ç¨‹
```

how to make it shows correctly?

I am using Php 5.3.10

Comment: Did you make sure that the page encoding is utf8? I.e. `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: @Jack would you post it as an answer, so i can accept is as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page encoding should be set properly (if not done already) via the response headers:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML file make sure this meta tag is inside your `<head></head>` tag:

```
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure you set correct meta in html.

   <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
2. set correct locale in php.

   setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");